# How rendering a slot using v-if based on element width dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I create a responsive component. The idea is when the window resizes happens is checked if the window width is lower than breakpoint 960px [(based on vuetify breakpoint)](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service-object). So, trigger a slot based on your respective slot directive (mobile or desktop).

The problem is: even when the component is rendered, he has the initial state has mobile, because `toolbarWidth` is equal to 0.

I want this to be dynamic.

Code:

```
  data() {
    return {
      toolbarWidth: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  computed: {
    isMobile() {
      return this.toolbarWidth < this.$vuetify.breakpoint.thresholds.sm
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize() {
      if (this.$refs.toolbar) {
        this.toolbarWidth = this.$refs.toolbar.clientWidth
      }
    }
  },
```

Slots inside template:

```
<v-menu v-if="isMobile">
  ...
  <slot name="actionsMobile" />
</v-menu>

<slot v-else name="actionsDesktop" />
```

Comment: Why you are not using `v-resize` directive? 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/resize/

Comment: @Mr. 

I didn't want to leave this attached to the template. The `handleResize` method performs the same function as this directive. I just need to get the initial width of the toolbar and pass it to the data.

Answer (score 0):

my advice is to use CSS instead Javascript to manage design , you can use for example Bootstrap class like col-12 for large screen col-md-12 for medium screen and col-sm-12 for small design .
There are a lot of options like

[image: bootstrap grid options]

or you can use media query :

```css
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

You can use these helpful links also:

- [media-query](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)
- [bootstrap grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue .

Comment: Thanks @rassakra for the reply. I need to hide based on the toolbar width. Unfortunately, these helpers apply only when breakpoints changes, but when I have my toolbar inside a small wrapper these changes don't happen.